# Using an "Array" of Strings in C

Tags: c

I need to store a large number of strings to be use by my program. I cannot statically allocate the memory - but I'm not sure how to design the code for the dynamic allocation such that I can access it as an array as each block won't be of the same size.

How should I proceed?

Comment: So you want an array of pointers to char

Answer (score 2):

What is unknown, the number of strings, size of strings, or both?

You can dynamically allocate an array of char *'s to hold each string `char **strings = (char**) malloc(NUM_OF_STRINGS * (sizeof(char*)));` calling `realloc()` as necessary to allocate more strings. For each string you add to the array of strings, also dynamically allocate with malloc `strings[index] = (char*) malloc(SIZE_OF_STRING);` You'll need to keep track of the number of these strings you allocate and resize the `strings` array accordingly. Each string will need to be free'd by iterating over the array of strings:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < stringCount; ++i)
{
    free(strings[i]);
}
```

Comment: yeah neither condition is known. What does the realloc() segment look like. 

Say I have a while loop `while(int args = scanf("%s", string))` where string is a char *.

Comment: You'll use some variable to track the number of strings currently in the `strings` array and the total size of the array. This is how you will index into the array to add another, but before that you'll need to check to make sure you are not  going out of bounds of the array. it will look something like `if (index == maxSize) { strings = (char**) realloc( maxSize * 2 * sizeof(char*)); maxSize *= 2;}` This should be done prior to assigning a new string to an element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of `char *`. These will be uninitialized to begin with. When you need to use one, use `malloc()` to allocate a buffer of the appropriate size (remember to leave space for the null character), or if you already have a string that you're copying from, use `strdup()` to allocate the memory and copy from it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate each string in the dynamic memory by strdup(), and thereafer - just use pointer ti this string. don't forget free(ptr), after string is used.

Example:

```
char *strings[10000]; // array for 10, 000 string pointers
int ndx = 0;
char strbuf[1000];

while(fgets(strbuf, sizeof(strbuf), f)
  strins[ndx++] = strdup(strbuf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:-

```
const char *a[20];
a[0] = "abc";
a[1] = "xyz";
.
.
.
.
a[19] = "try";
```

Comment: well, neither the size of the strings nor the size of the string list are known.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate a small array in the beginning of your program and then expand it by using [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).